# How to Rollback data inserted into 3 tables at once in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables and I am updating and inserting into all those tables.

My requirement is if we get any error at table 2 or table 3, I need to rollback all the inserted and updated data from all tables.

If all Insert and updates are succeeded then we need to commit for all tables at once.

Table 1 :

```
UPDATE table1
SET Name = 'A'
WHERE Id =1

INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT *  
    FROM Table
```

Table 2:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET Name = 'A'
WHERE Id =1

INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table
```

Table 3:

```
UPDATE table3 
SET Name = 'A'
WHERE Id =1

INSERT INTO Table3
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Google and learn about Transactions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TRY...CATCH` and transactions:

```
--Begin the TRY
BEGIN TRY

    --Start a transaction    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION MyTran; --Might want a better name

    --Do all the operations    
    UPDATE table1
    SET Name = 'A'
    WHERE Id = 1;

    INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT *
    FROM [Table];

    UPDATE table2
    SET Name = 'A'
    WHERE Id = 1;

    INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT *
    FROM [Table];

    UPDATE table3
    SET Name = 'A'
    WHERE Id = 1;

    INSERT INTO Table3
    SELECT *
    FROM [Table];

    --All successful, so COMMIT
    COMMIT TRANSACTION MyTran;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    --Roll back everything on failure
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MyTran;
    THROW;

END CATCH;
```